# Lyapunov-Function with the Method of Aizermann/Krasovski

Tags: control-theory, nonlinear-system, stability-theory, linearization, lyapunov-functions

Consider the following autonomous system:

$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x}_1 &= -2 x_1 \\
\dot{x}_2 &= -2 x_2 + 2 x_1 x_2^2
\end{align}
$$

Derive for the equlibrium $x_1 = x_2 = 0$ a Lyapunov-function and its domain with

1. the Method of Aizermann (linearization), and
2. the Method of Krasovski.

Comment: Can you please provide a link or other (preferably online) reference for these two methods?  I've never heard of them.  Or, you might try and explain them.  Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for answer, in the link below I have uploaded few notes describe the both methods, but still can't implement them on the system described in the question. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IvEwFEywFAOFWFbzMNdyUxTFvOICv4kE

Comment: Thanks I'll check the out. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you too. Cheers!

Comment: Please add those notes to the question itself, namely links can break, in which case the context of your question might be lost on people who might visit this page in the future.

Comment: I added the link to the question